# Conditionally copy a potentially nonexisting file with gnu make

Tags: copy, conditional-statements, gnu-make

I'm compiling a library called `libCMSDataFormat.so`.

When `libCMSDataFormat.so` gets compiled, it potentially makes one (or more) `.pcm` files (this is platform-dependent).
If these files are made, they should be copied to another location (called $OBJ). 
But if they don't exist, the program is supposed to end normally, i.e. without an error.

The following works if the `.pcm` file gets made, but it fails for the platform where the `.pcm` file is not generated (i.e. copy gives an error since no file is found)

```
SRC=../src
OBJ=../lib
all: $(OBJ) $(OBJ)/libCMSDataFormat.so MoveFile
.Phony : MoveFile
MoveFile: $(OBJ)/libCMSDataFormat.so
ifeq ($(*.pcm $(SRC)),)
    @echo "copying.."
    cp $(SRC)/*_rdict.pcm $(OBJ)
else
    @echo "no .pcm found!"
endif

 (Rule for `libCMSDataFormat.so` follows which might (or might not!) create one or more `*.pcm` files in `$(SRC)`.
```

Any suggestions to get this to work for both cases are welcome, preferably also for the case more than one `.pcm` is generated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering is that the conditional is being evaluated too early.  If you use the $(if) function, then its evaluation will be deferred until the rule is executed.  This means it'll see any .pcm files created as a side-effect of early build stages.

```
SRC=../src
OBJ=../lib
all: $(OBJ) $(OBJ)/libCMSDataFormat.so MoveFile
.Phony : MoveFile
MoveFile: $(OBJ)/libCMSDataFormat.so
        $(if $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.pcm), \
            @echo "copying.."; \
            cp $(SRC)/*_rdict.pcm $(OBJ) \
          , \
            @echo "no .pcm found!")
```

Of course, one option is simply to always run `cp`, but ignore its return code (you can do this by prefixing the first line of the recipe with `-`).  It's not recommended, however, as it can also hide errors that occur when the .pcm files exist but fail to copy.

Comment: Hi Droid Coder, many thanks for the friendly reply! In the meantime I've found an (ugly!) work-around, but I'll look into your suggestion asap. Thanks for your efforts!
Merijn